# HEAD and master denotations using github

Tags: github

I have been fumbling around on github, and now with some help I have managed to make my branch the local master. however, I get these lines that i guess are tracking where things have been changed. But I don't want them!! I really just want my current files to become the new master as they are.

What exactly are these lines for? And how do I suppress them?

```
<<<<<<< HEAD

=======
>>>>>>> master
```

Comment: there is generally lots of code between them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those lines signal merge conflicts in Git.
When you do a merge, git is generally good at automatically working out how to merge files together, however there are some cases where it cannot - for example, when both branches are adding to the same kind of area in the same file, you get a merge conflict.

In these cases, those lines will be drawn around the boundary of the conflict. The section above the `=======` belongs to the `HEAD` ref (or whatever is displayed after `<<<<<<<`). The section below belongs to the `master` ref (or whatever is displayed after `>>>>>>>`).

It's up to you to delete these lines and make the according edit to the code. If you only want to take what is on the HEAD ref in the final version of the code (post-merge), then you delete everything below the `======` line - and visa versa if you want to only take what is on the master branch. Of course, you can also take both versions of the code by just removing the markers.

You can see [the git manual](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) for more information.